# Does Showon attribute for list options work with Joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x, form-fields-types, showon

I have tried the following exact example in the Joomla documentation:

[Showon attribute for list options](https://docs.joomla.org/index.php?title=List_form_field_type#Showon_attribute_for_list_options)

```
<field
    name="fielda"
    type="list"
    label="FIELDA_LABEL"
    description="FIELDA_DESC"
    >
    <option value="editor">TYPE_EDITOR</option>
    <option value="text">TYPE_TEXT</option>
    <option value="textarea">TYPE_TEXTAREA</option>
</field>

<field
    name="fieldb"
    type="list"
    label="FIELDB_LABEL"
    description="FIELDB_DESC"
    >
    <option value="0">JNO</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option
        showon="fielda:text,textarea"
        value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option
        showon="fielda:text"
        value="3">Option 3</option>
</field>
```

I rendered the fields with the code:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('fielda'); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('fieldb'); ?>
```

In the documentation it says:

> Since Joomla 3.9.0 one can use the showon attribute for option tags in a list field.

But I'm trying in Joomla 4 and seems it doesn't work. All options in *fieldb*, appear with any option of *fielda*

Does **Showon** attribute for list options work with Joomla 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I manage to get this working in my component.

I needed to add the javascript in the layout, like this:

```
$wa = $this->document->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->useScript('showon');
```

Comment: Looks like this is not working for groupedlist options :(